# How to iterate through a map in a vector of maps?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, maps

Code written in C++

Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio

I have a vector of maps.
First I want to iterate through the first map, get its 'first' and 'second' and save them in some other structure I built (a map of vectors).
And then I'll iterate through the left maps in my "vector of maps" and do the same...

Here's my vector of maps:

```
typedef vector<map<string,unsigned int>> myvec;
```

And here's the function that should do the work:

```
void Coogle::make_index(const myvec& the_vec)
{
    //SCAN THE FIRST MAP
    map<string,unsigned int>::iterator map_iter;
    index::iterator idx_iter = the_index.begin();
    for(map_iter=the_vec[0].begin(); map_iter!=the_vec[0].end(); ++map_iter)
    {

    }
}
```

The 'for' loop should iterate through the first map in the vector.
I declared a map iterator because I need it to iterate though the map! Right?
Why isn't it working?

the error:

> IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands

Thanks a lot !!!

---

OK now I identified this iterator:

```
index::iterator idx_iter = the_index.begin();
```

And here's my 'index':

```
typedef map<string,vector<unsigned int>> index;
```

And inside the mentioned 'for' loop I did the following:

```
    for(map_iter=the_vec[0].begin(); map_iter!=the_vec[0].end(); ++map_iter)
    {
        /*#1*/ idx_iter->first = map_iter->first;
        /*#2*/ idx_iter->second[0] = map_iter->second;
        /*#3*/ idx_iter++;
    }
```

#2 seems to be ok. But #1 generates an error:

> IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands

It's the same error like the one before so I'm guessing it's a similar problem.
Is it?

**edit:** To be more clear, what I wanna do is add from **const myvec& the_vec** to the 'i' location (in this case '0') to my index.

Again :

```
typedef vector<map<string,unsigned int>> myvec;
typedef map<string,vector<unsigned int>> index;
```

Thank you!

Comment: No,that iterator is for the map at the vector's first map element.

Comment: @Mahesh, as Slims said, the iterator is for the first map in the vector. And why cbegin() and cend()? I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`the_vec` is passed as reference to constant, so you need `const_iterator`:

```
map<string,unsigned int>::const_iterator map_iter;
```

Comment: Can you see the sequenced question below please? :)

Comment: @AdamDe You mean the question that has incorrectly been posted as an answer and should have been posted either as a separate question or as an update of your existing question?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you can't modify the keys in a map, since they are required to be kept in order. If you want to replace all the elements in the index, then it's probably best to clear it first, then add the new elements:

```
the_index.clear();
for(map_iter=the_vec[0].begin(); map_iter!=the_vec[0].end(); ++map_iter)
{
    the_index[map_iter->first].push_back(map_iter->second);
}
```

Comment: I neither want to clear it nor modify it. I just want to add an element to my index.

My index is:

typedef map<string,vector<unsigned int>> index;

So isn't there a suitable 'inesrt' command for this?

Thank you

Comment: OK, if you just want to add new elements then use my code without the `clear()` bit; or use `insert` if you'd rather (although that gets a bit verbose unless you can use C++11 initialiser lists to write `the_index.insert({map_iter->first, {map_iter->second}})`). Your code was iterating through the index and trying to change the keys, so I assumed you wanted to replace the existing elements.

Comment: map_iter->second is an int.
    the_index
consists of a string, and a vector of ints.
I understand the
    the_index[map_iter->first].
But does the continuation
    ( .push_back(map_iter->second) )
create a vector and a
    map_iter->second
assigned to it?

Comment: @AdamDe: `operator[]` creates an element if it wasn't already there, so the continuation adds that value to the newly created vector. Although you will also need to deal with the situation where the key already exists, so it might be better to use `insert` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to iterate through a `map` that contains keys of `string`s and values of `vector`s of `string`s:

```
for( map<string, vector<string>>::iterator ii = timeZonesMap.begin(); ii != timeZonesMap.end(); ++ii)
{
    cout << ii->first << ": " << endl;
    for(std::vector<string>::iterator it = ii->second.begin(); it != ii->second.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future